# Trying to make an LDAP search query on Ruby on Rails but keep getting error can't quote Net::LDAP::Entry

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, active-directory, ldap

So, I'm trying to make a query on my `LDAP` and keep getting error :

```
can't quote Net::LDAP::Entry
```

This is my authenticate_user.rb:

```
class AuthenticateUser
  def self.call(*args)
    new(*args).call
  end

  def initialize(username, password)
    @username = "#{username}@company.com"
    @password = password
  end

  def call
    search_title_if_valid_user
  end

  private
  def search_title_if_valid_user
  filter = Net::LDAP::Filter.eq("objectclass", "person")
    ldap = Net::LDAP.new(
      host: "company.com",
      port: 389,
      base: "DC=company,DC=com",
      auth: { method: :simple, username: @username, password: @password }
    )

    ldap.search(filter: filter, attributes: ["title"]) if ldap.bind
  end
end
```

And my sessions_controller:

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController
  def new
  end

  def create
    username = params[:nome]
    password = params[:password]

    title = AuthenticateUser.call(username, password)
    puts(title.first.inspect)

    if title
      user = User.create_with(nome: username).find_or_create_by(NumeroEmpregado: title)
      session[:user_id] = user.id
      redirect_to '/'
    else
      flash[:error] = "Erro!              \nNúmero de Empregado e/ou password incorrecto(a)"
      redirect_to '/login'
     end
  end

  def destroy
    session[:user_id] = nil
    redirect_to '/index/new'
  end
end
```

This code is checking if the user that is trying to log in is present in the `LDAP` if he is on the `LDAP and SQL DB` he will get a session on my `webapp` and proceed, if he is on the `LDAP` and isn´t on the `SQL DB` a row on my `SQLSERVER` database will be created with the `employee number` `(NumeroEmpregado, title)` and when I'm trying to get `title` from the LADP to create the field I get `can't quote Net::LDAP::Entry` I've tried different filters, some have given me `nil` and others `[]`

- Is something wrong with my code? How do I fix this?